# foreach inside while loop returning duplicate data

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

**Context:** I have an ordering form, that has a html select and a number input. so a user selects the item and enter the amount they want of that item, these are sent as arrays to the hander page. `$_POST['item'];` is an array of id's that I want to select product info from the database with. `$amount = $_POST['amount'];` is just an array of the amounts of each item.

**Problem:** Each row is being duplicated by the amount of rows there are, so in this case it's returning three rows, but duplicating each one, three times.

**Objective:** All I'm trying to do is foreach `$_POST['item']` get that rows data from the database and show them and the respective amounts in a table, so the user can confirm the order.

handle.php

```
<?php 
$item = $_POST['item']; // array of product ids to select data from db
$amount = $_POST['amount']; // array of amounts of each product the user ordered
$note = $_POST['note'];
$i = 0;

$each = implode(',',$item);

$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * 
          FROM `products` 
         WHERE `id` IN (' . $each . ')');


        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Item</th>
              <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
              <th scope="col">Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

    <?php 
while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $product_id = $row['id'];
    $product_name = $row['name'];
    $product_price = $row['price'];
    $row['quantity'] = $amount[$row['id']];

    print "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    print "</pre>";
    ?>

    <tr>
     <td><?php echo $product_name;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['quantity'];?></td>
     <td><?php echo $product_price;?></td>
    </tr>


<?php } ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` fetches __one row__. Why not use the code that already provided in a manual?

Comment: I've been told by serval different  people to change something, but not how to fix the damn thing. I don't know what i'm doing wrong.. sorry, i'm just really frustrated with this.

Comment: It's more commonly done as `while ($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`

Comment: @NigelRen Ok, but you still get the duplicating data. i moved it to outside of the foreach loop of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but you are reassigning

```
$key = array() ;
```

immediately after your

```
foreach ($amount as $key)
```

That's causing your

```
<td><?php echo $key;?></td>
```

to try to echo an array because you overwrote the value of $key assigned by the foreach.

<strike>Your post does not detail what data is getting duplicated so I can't really address that in this answer.</strike>

You are duplicating the same three rows because you are setting

```
$new = array_combine($item, $amount);
```

Then your SQL is grabbing the rows

```
$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * 
      FROM `products` 
     WHERE `id` IN (' . $each . ')');
```

Then you're looping over the same items with

```
foreach ($new as $key => $val) {
```

If you want to display the items you found in the SQL then you shouldn't have the

```
foreach ($new as $key => $val) {
```

inside your while() loop. Your while() is already looping over the rows returned for those items. This assumes you only have one product per item number.

If you expect one **or more** 'products' to be returned for each item number then you should be executing your SQL while looping through foreach($new), but that doesn't appear to be what the top part of your code is doing.

After some back and forth we've identified the issue: the amounts need to be tied to the item numbers.

You are getting items numbers and quantities as arrays from your HTML. So you need to loop through the items and associate them with your quantities.

```
// where your qualities will live
$quantities = array() ; 

// loop through the array of items you received and match them up with their quantity 
foreach($item as $k=>$id) { 
    $quantities[$id] = $amount[$k] ; 
}
```

Then you can access the quantity in your while loop using:

```
$row['quantity'] = $quantities[$row['id']] ;
```

Comment: The question has been updated, I also added an update as to what data is being duplicated.

Comment: @bob, I added info addressing your 'duplicate row' issue.

Comment: that is very helpful. I'm expecting one product to be returned for each item. I've been reading about arrays and array functions all day to try and understand this.

Comment: If I put the foreach loop outside of the while loop then I can't access it's values, if inside it shows the last result as many times as there are rows.

Comment: You can see here I'm getting 2 for all of the quantities, when they are all different: https://imgur.com/a/pRB8IZF

Comment: @bob, you're setting the amount in your $new and not getting it from $row.

Comment: I've removed all of that, as per your answer. I've updated the question.

Comment: Your foreach ($amount as $key => $val) { $row['quantity'] = $val; }  is **inside** your while loop. You don't need this foreach() at all.

Comment: if I remove the foreach then how do I get the amounts to display for each row? (they aren't in the database, they are in the array `$_POST['amounts']`)

Comment: You don't need a loop. You want to get the quantity using the item number. The you need to get them with $row['quantity'] = $amount[$row['item number field']]

Comment: If I use `$row['quantity'] = $amount[$row['id']];` is returns only the last element from the `$amount` array and is displayed in the first of the `$row` array.

Comment: If you are storing the quantities properly in $amount, then it should get the correct quantity. Dump the values of $amount and make sure the id<=>quantity is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172405/discussion-between-mr-glass-and-bob).